# Perl - can't flush STDOUT or STDERR

Tags: perl

Perl 5.14 from stock Ubuntu Precise repos.  Trying to write a simple wrapper to monitor progress on copying from one stream to another:

```
use IO::Handle;
while ($bufsize = read (SOURCE, $buffer, 1048576)) {
    STDERR->printflush ("Transferred $xferred of $sendsize bytes\n");
    $xferred += $bufsize;
    print TARGET $buffer;
}
```

This does not perform as expected (writing a line each time the 1M buffer is read).  I end up seeing the first line (with a blank value of $xferred), and then nothing until everything flushes on the 7th and 8th lines (on an 8MB transfer).  Been pounding my brains out on this for hours - I've read the perldocs, I've read the classic "Suffering from Buffering" article, I've tried everything from select and $|++ to IO::Handle to binmode (STDERR, "::unix") to you name it.  I've also tried flushing TARGET with each line using IO::Handle (TARGET->flush).  No dice.

Has anybody else ever encountered this?  I don't have any ideas left.  Sleeping one second "fixes" the problem, but obviously I don't want to sleep a second every time I read a buffer just so my progress will output on the screen!

FWIW, the problem is exactly the same whether I'm outputting to STDERR or STDOUT.

Comment: The handle originally assigned to STDERR starts autoflushed, so if you don't mess with it, just a normal `print` would do.

Comment: @ikegami - sorry, I misspoke when typing that.  I do see all 8 lines for the 8MB transferred (buffered in 1MB chunks as shown), but they appear all at once at the end of the transfer.  Question is edited appropriately.

Comment: @ikegami - a normal print did not do; I started out just using normal print and that gave me the buffered behavior, then I tried setting $|, then I tried using IO::Handle's autoflush and flush methods, then I tried syswrite instead of print, then I tried printflush as shown above.  Nothing changes the behavior, including using STDOUT instead of STDERR - I get the first line of output, then a long pause while the transfer goes through, then all eight lines flushing at once at the end of the transfer.

Comment: Where are `SOURCE` and `TARGET` opened to?

Comment: I think we need to see the entire Perl source.

Comment: Is it possible that your transfer speed kind of varies and that is why it seems to "flush" lines 2-8? So the first line takes a bit longer, lines 2-8 go in a flurry. I have tested this with way bigger files than 8MB over here (8MB would always finish instantly), and I did see lag at some points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl [`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) calls [`fread(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fread.html), not [`read(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/read.html).

This means that it goes through `libc` and *may be* using an internal buffer larger than yours; i.e., it gets all the data there is to be received and then quickly throws it at you in 1MB increments.

If this conjecture is correct, the solution *might be* to use [`sysread`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html), which calls `read(2)`, instead of `read`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  The problem wasn't that STDERR wasn't flushing, the problem was that my INPUT wasn't flushing to the routine processing it, despite the stated buffer size in the read call!